# Unauthorized error while sending push notification in GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I am trying to send push notification message from server(application server) to mobile device through GCM. i tried below code but getting "connection refused error" but when i tested using web service tester i am getting "unauthorized error"  as per the attachment. I am using server API key, no ip addresss are whishlisted.i have enabled google cloud messaging for android  API also don't know the reason. Please help.
[web service tester error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5hZX.png)

code:

```
        String google_server_key="";
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("GCMServerKey");
        Enumeration <String> keys = rb.getKeys();
        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) 
        {
            google_server_key = keys.nextElement();

        }

        try
        {

        String pushNotificationMessage="nagesh";
        String regID="APA91bEZD2MFH7TzMvry1UR2ezqTSAwCbqRgIZ8qXo_h559TYId29j3u2zPyHzxiZrA65tVhtPlY9O77LnLRbqJf585YmwYccBrGoQ5OjPAz4xT_JfIGJ1AEyjq9EUEhawc2V4kMrIar";              //pushMessage.getRegId();
        Sender sender = new Sender(google_server_key);
        Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
                .delayWhileIdle(true).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, pushNotificationMessage).build();

         Result result = sender.send(message,regID , 1);

        }
        catch (IOException ioe) 
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: check the  Sender sender = new Sender(google_server_key); line for google_server_key. Most of time, unauthorized means server_key is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [Downstream message error response code](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) documentation.

> Authentication Error   401
>
> The sender account used to send a message couldn't be authenticated. Possible causes are:
>
> - Authorization header missing or with invalid syntax in HTTP request.
> - Invalid project number sent as key.
> - Key valid but with GCM service disabled.
> - Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server Key IPs.
>
> Check that the token you're sending inside the Authentication header is the correct API key associated with your project. See [Checking the validity of an API Key](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#checkAPIkey) for details.